# python-3.x | Как сократить цикл while?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def main():
 do_something()
while True:
    try:
        main()
    except:
        main()
    finally:
     try:
        main()
     except:
        main()
     finally:
        ...
```

Имеется такой код. **finally** можно прописывать до бесконечности... Мне нужно сделать, чтобы **main()** так и не смог выполниться. Какой есть ещё способ, кроме прописывания **finally** это сделать?

### Решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О БОЖЕ МОЙ, ЧТО ЭТО?!

Comment: Само собой прописан код вместо do_something(), но он не важен. Мне нужно не дать выполниться команде main().

Comment: Покажите код полностью, то что делает do_something()

Comment: Влад Дикей, [**аргументы**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7120/199934), почему отклонил Вашу правку. Как видите, его уже заблокировали. Надеюсь, подобные персонажи никак не могут повлиять на Ваше настроение. Спасибо.

Comment: я не писал что нужно убрать except

Comment: @MelisZhoroev Подправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял раз вам нужно чтобы при вызове функции она так сказать не срабатывалась. Сделайте для нее исключение, как в примере пока пользователь не введет значение `0` программа будет выдавать ошибку и будет выдавать пользователю повторить действие.

```
def a(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("Okey")
    else:
        print('Не продолжается функция')
        raise Exception('Error')


def b():
    print("Try again")


while True:
    try:
        a(int(input("Введите данные")))

    except Exception:
        b()
```

[Проверка](https://repl.it/@Cmertho/TremendousPlushDeskscan)

Comment: Всё получилось. Огромное Вам спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Обработайте ошибку самом main функции, и не надо делать except без  параметра или рекурсия на помощь

```
def do_something():
    # ваш код

def main():
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        main()
```

Comment: Ошибки нет как таковой... Есть longpoll сервер, который обрывает соединение через 25 секунд простоя, это никак не решается к сожалению. Мне просто нужен способ, чтобы запускать def_main заного. Пока работает только многократное прописывание, вот и спросил, возможно-ли это заменить чем-либо.

Comment: @ВладДикей Подправил ответ

Comment: В таком случае сразу выполняется main() И бот в итоге не работает. while True в конце кода заставляет бота переприсоединяться к longpoll. Если этого не прописать и бот не будет никому писать в течении ~25 секунд, вся консоль IDLE будет в ошибке через ~25 секунд, что удалённый хост разорвал соединение.

Comment: @ВладДикей Еще раз подправил ответ, вам нужно заюзать рекурсию

Comment: Всё так же... Получается мгновенное выполнение функции, и в итоге бот не работает.

Comment: Проблема решена, использовал предложенное решение от пользователя Twiss.

Comment: @ВладДикей окей, удачи вам, но я вам настоятельно рекомендую изучить питон, вы очень и очень плохо разбираетесь, даже в синтаксисе языка